# Unknown Runtime Error in IE 8 with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I have written a simple AngularJS based HTML. It has an array of predefined items and `Add` and `Delete` buttons are provided for adding or removing the items from the list. `Delete` button is a custom directive. Below is the code sample: (`<delete-button>` is a custom directive)

**HTML**

Item

```
    <p>
        <label>Price</label> <input type="text" ng-model="price" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItems()">Add</button>
    </p>
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Item Price</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items|filter:name|orderBy:predicate">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price | currency}}</td>
            <td><delete-button>Remove</delete-button></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$scope.addItems = function() {
        $scope.start();
        var newItem = {name: $scope.name , price: $scope.price};
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
        $scope.complete();
    };
myModule.directive("deleteButton", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<button class='btn btn-warning' ng-click='removeItem(item)' ng-transclude></button>"
    };
});
```

The code runs fine on Chrome and Firfox, but when I tried to run it on IE 8, it gave `"Error: Unknown Runtime Error"`in the console. There is no other log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems IE 8 is unable to handle the custom directives. The code is running fine after removing the custom directive. [IE documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) states that for custom element directives, we need to call `document.createElement('custom-element')`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this [article about using Angular with IE8 and earlier](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).
But the problem with your code is probably that you are restricting the directive to an element, in IE8 you can't do that, use Attribute instead.

```
myModule.directive("deleteButton", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: "<button class='btn btn-warning' ng-click='removeItem(item)' ng-transclude></button>"
    };
});
```